# How to get some output from an Oracle Data Modeler Rhino script?

Tags: oracle, rhino

I'm working on Rhino scripts to run into Oracle Data Modeler tool and sometimes I need to get a simple output from these scripts, like a list of objects (entities, tables, etc) and some data about them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique that can be used is to create a Note object and use this function to update the note contents with some arbitrary text.

```
var print = (function() {
    var notes = model.getNoteSet().toArray();
    var note = null;
    if (notes.length > 0) {
        note = notes[0];
        note.comment = "";
    }
    return function() {
        if (note != null) {
            var s = String(note.comment);
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                s += arguments[i];
            }
            note.comment = s;
        }
    }
})();
```

You can use it this way:

```
print("This ", "is ", "a test", "\n");
```

I know I can use java API to open a text file or something like that, but update a note content seems simpler to me.

Comment: to me, model was not defined =/